# System.Linq to String issue with GET request

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, web-services, rest

Why is it when I do this:

```
    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string uri1 = "http://localhost:8000/Service/GetMessage/{anything}";
        string tagUri = uri1.Replace("{anything}", textBox21.Text);
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(tagUri);
        var MessageID = xDoc.Descendants("Message")
                             .Select(n => new
                             {
                                 MessageID = n.Element("MessageID").Value,
                             })
            .ToString();

        textBox1.Text = MessageID;
```

I get this really strange output?

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f__AnonymousType7`1[System.String]]
```

But yet when I change ToString to ToList and use:

```
dataGridView10.DataSource = MessageID;
```

It displays it correctly? Really struggling to find out a way to take my incoming GET request to string?

Comment: Are you expecting only one value for MessageID?  Try `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.ToString()`.  LINQ queries will return a collection (even if it's only one element) by design, and when you call .ToString() on it you get the strange output (drawing a blank on the technical reason for why .ToString() returns what you're seeing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LINQ query is getting a collection by nature of the call to `.Descendants`.  If there's only one, you can use a `.Single()` or `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` to get the only (or First) item in the list.

Then it would be

```
textbox1.Text = MessageID.MessageID;
```

Though you more likely want to do something like this:

```
var MessageId = xDoc.Element("Message").Element("MessageID").Value;
```

But I'm somewhat guessing, as I don't know the format or content of your XML.

Answer (score 1):

There are others here who can give you a more detailed explanation, but here's what I think is happening (expanded from my comment above).

By default, LINQ queries return a collection, even when there's only one result.  When you call `.ToString()` on the that collection, you get the fully qualified name of the type of the Object.  See [Object.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) - which in this case I believe is the weird output you get.

You're probably looking for a single result (MessageID), so you could use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.ToString()`, like this:

```
var MessageID = xDoc.Descendants("Message")
                .Select(n => new
                {
                    MessageID = n.Element("MessageID").Value,
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that `n.Element("MessageID").Value` will return a string, which you can then assign to the TextBox.

When you convert the query to a List, you are able to bind it to the DataGridView's DataSource because DataSource takes objects that implement one of the `IList` interfaces (`IList` in the case of a generic list).